# How can I change the URL the user is navigating using Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to, if the user permission, change the URL the user is navigating. Can I do it?

Comment: Do you just want to change the url of the current tab?

Comment: Yes, I do. can I do it?

Comment: Use `chrome.tabs.update` for that.
Do you want to display a dialog asking the user for permission when doing so?